# MST Proof (Kleinburg & Tordos)

Tags: graphs, greedy-algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree

Consider the Minimum Spanning Tree Problem on an undirected graph
G = (V, E), with a cost ≥ 0 on each edge, where the costs may not all
be different. If the costs are not all distinct, there can in general be
many distinct minimum-cost solutions. Suppose we are given a spanning
tree T ⊆ E with the guarantee that for every e ∈ T, e belongs to some
minimum-cost spanning tree in G. Can we conclude that T itself must
be a minimum-cost spanning tree in G? Give a proof or a counterexample
with explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest counterexample. The edge set $\{10, 12\}$ is not a minimum spanning tree (MST). However, edge 10 is in the edge set $\{10, 02\}$, an MST. Edge 12 is in the edge set $\{12, 02\}$, an MST.

[image: graph made using graphonline.ru/en/]

---

Note that there are two edges of equal weight in the above counterexample.

(**Question.**) What if no edges have the same weight?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following non-minimum spanning tree.

```
           1
 +-------------------+
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |                   |
2|←                 →|2
 |                   |
 |                   |
 |         ↓         |
 +-------------------+
           1
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate?